# How to do image pattern matching like triangle, circle matching in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

Suppose one image like circle image is there. Then I want draw circle over that image, then check two image is same or not in iOS. I tried image matching using CGPoint, but for circle and triangle what to do.

Comment: Define "same". Not one pixel with even a slightly a different color?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question ?

Comment: Are the circle of same size? or, etc... Try clarify a little more

Answer (score 0):

For matching two triangles you may have two choices:

- define two areas in each traingle, then calculate areas ratio, they must have the same ratio if they are matched
- try to detect three points of each triangle, then calculate the [barycentre](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2004/HF04/coordinates_aicm04.pdf) coordinates
  they are invarinat

For circle, if you could easily to represent each circle by a triangle which its points cross that circle, you can find the invariance by the previous steps.